# want to select only seven days from today only in jsp?

Tags: jsp, datepicker

I want to enable only seven days from today and disable all the remaining days in the datepicker.
i'm using the following code for date picker

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
      <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
      <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {minDate:today,maxDate:'08/10/2015'}
        $("#datepicker").datepicker(options);
      });



      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
     function validate(){
//  var labId=document.getElementById('testname').value;
    var testdate=document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
//  var status=document.forms["CreateSchedule"]["status"].value;


    var date=new Date();
    var y=date.getDate()-1;
    var x=date.getMonth()+ 1;

    if(y<10){
        y='0'+y;
    }
    if(x<10){
        x='0'+x;
    }
    var todayDate  =  x + "/" + y + "/" + date.getFullYear();
    if(testdate==todayDate){
        alert('You have selected todays date');
        alert('Please enter other date');
        return false;
    }
    if(testdate==""){
        alert('Enter date');
        return false;
    }
    return true;


}
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name='myform' onsubmit='return validate();'>
        Slot Date:<input id="datepicker" name='Gouse'/>


        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i'm using chrome, eclipse Indigo.

Please give your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the code below will help,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
                    minDate: 0,
                    maxDate: '+1w',
                    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.weekends}
    $("#datepicker").datepicker(options);
});
```

Will enable only one week from today. See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wANFJ/97/)